# SwiftyJSON - Parsing object that contains arrays

Tags: arrays, json, xcode, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON to parse through an array of Collections objects. 
Each collection has 1 ID string, 1 url string, several other strings, and then three arrays: owner, items, and element_texts.

I am trying to get all of the "text" strings within each "element_texts" array. [Here a link to the url I'm referencing.](http://handheldart.org/api/collections/?pretty_print)

And here's the code I'm currently using:

```
var labels = [String: UILabel]()
var strings = [String]()
var objects = [[String: String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlString = "http://handheldart.org/api/collections/"
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)
            parseJSON(json)
        }
    }
}

func parseJSON(json: JSON) {

        for result in json["id"]["url"]["public"]["featured"]["added"]["modified"]["owner"]["items"]["element_texts"].arrayValue {
            let html = result["html"].stringValue
            let textName = result["text"].stringValue

            let obj = ["html": html, "textName": textName]
            print (textName)
            objects.append(obj)
        }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

My object count stays 0. Any help would be appreciated! I think it's just a simple matter of misunderstanding how to parse through everything...

Comment: You didn't understand your structure I think. Try to print `json`, then `json["id"]`, then `json["id"]["url"]`. What part works, what part doesn't work.

Comment: In parseJSON, if I do something like "for result in json.arrayValue { let collectionID = json["id"].stringValue }" that works fine when I print(collectionID). It's when I try to access an array like "owner" or "element_texts" that I get confused. EDIT: Oh yeah, I see what you mean when I try to print json["id"]["url"]... Huh. I've seen that sort of setup before but you're right, I'm misunderstanding how it works

Comment: `owner` and `element_texts` is at the same level that the "first" "id". so `json["owner"]` or `json["element_texts"]`. Also, there is an array at top level or your JSON, so that's quite strange that it works.

Comment: Ahh, I see now json["1"]["2"] only works when 2 is within 1 and so on. I thought you needed to list out every key in order before you could access a later key. Turns out I can just say `for result in json.arrayValue { let element_texts = result["element_texts"].arrayValue }` and go from there. Easier than I thought. Thanks!